# add multiple workbooks using checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I have a userform with 2 checkboxes, when the user clicks on the send button it should copy the sheet 1 from currentWorkbook to a new workbook. If the user clicks in one of checkboxes (1 or 2)  it works but if I clicks on the 2 checkboxes at the same time it doesn't work.

My goal is if the user clicks on the 2 checkboxes, it copies the sheet 1 from currentWorkbook to 2 new workbooks.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim theNewWorkbook As Workbook
Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
Dim industry As String
Dim dttoday As String

Set currentWorkbook = Workbooks("blabla" & ".xlsm")
Set theNewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
currentWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

If one= True Then
currentWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy before:=theNewWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    With ActiveSheet
        .ListObjects(1).Name = "one"
    End With
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("one").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        Array("bla", "ble", "bli", "blo"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

'Save File

industry = "one "
dttoday = VBA.format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy")
saveLocation = "C:\blabla" & industry & dttoday & ".xlsx"
sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=saveLocation, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If sFileSaveName <> "False" Then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
theNewWorkbook.Close

End If

If two = True Then
currentWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy before:=theNewWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    With ActiveSheet
        .ListObjects(1).Name = "two"
    End With
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("two").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        Array("bla", "ble", "bli"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

'Save File

industry = "two "
dttoday = VBA.format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy")
saveLocation = "C:\blabla_" & industry & dttoday & ".xlsx"
sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=saveLocation, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If sFileSaveName <> "False" Then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
End If
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably caused by your relying on ActiveSheet.  If `one` is true, it's code may have changed which workbook/sheet is active when you get to `two`.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/445425) on how to solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the following:

- If checkbox `one` is checked create a new workbook with a copy of `Sheet1` from the current workbook in it and name the table on the copied sheet 'one'.
- If checkbox `two` is checked create a new workbook with a copy `Sheet1` from the current workbook in it and name the table on the copied sheet 'two'.
- Do both if both checkboxes are checked.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim theNewWorkbook As Workbook
Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
Dim industry As String
Dim dttoday As String

    Set currentWorkbook = Workbooks("blabla" & ".xlsm")

    If one = True Then
        currentWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
        Set theNewWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        With theNewWorkbook
            With .ActiveSheet
                .ListObjects(1).Name = "one"
                .ListObjects("one").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
                                                     Array("bla", "ble", "bli"), _
                                                     Operator:=xlFilterValues
                .Range(.Rows("2:2"), .Rows("2:2").End(xlDown)).Delete
                .ShowAllData
            End With


            'Save File

            industry = "one "
            dttoday = Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy")
            saveLocation = "C:\blabla" & industry & dttoday & ".xlsx"
            sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=saveLocation, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
            If sFileSaveName <> "False" Then
                .SaveAs sFileSaveName
            End If
            .Close
        End With
    End If

    If two = True Then
        currentWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
        Set theNewWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        With theNewWorkbook
            With .ActiveSheet
                .ListObjects(1).Name = "two"
                .ListObjects("two").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
                                                     Array("bla", "ble", "bli", "blo"), _
                                                     Operator:=xlFilterValues
                .Range(.Rows("2:2"), .Rows("2:2").End(xlDown)).Delete
                .ShowAllData
            End With


            'Save File

            industry = "two "
            dttoday = Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy")
            saveLocation = "C:\blabla" & industry & dttoday & ".xlsx"
            sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=saveLocation, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
            If sFileSaveName <> "False" Then
                .SaveAs sFileSaveName
            End If
            .Close
        End With
    End If
    
    Unload Me
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you @norie for your help. I tested and it works till deleting the rows. I get an error message saying "can't move cells in a filtered range or table" - i dont' understand why I get this error

Comment: Do you only want to copy the headings from the table to the new sheet(s)? I.e. no data

Comment: no, I want to copy everything and then filter and delete what I don't need. It runs till adding the filters but doesn't delete, I get an error

Comment: nevermind, I had some cells groupped preventing me from deleting the rows. Now it works :)  thank you a lot!